# Consulting Engineer

Tags: project-management, consulting

I don't understand the role of a consulting engineer. Is it a good idea to be a consulting engineer? Will I get chance to work close to the projects or I will be working on sidelines?

Comment: Job titles aren’t descriptions of the work that will be done, and every company defines jobs differently.  You would need to ask the company these questions.

Comment: " Is it a good idea to be a consulting engineer?"  If you don't understand the role, then it probably is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

> Will I get chance to work close to the projects or I will be working on sidelines?

Neither, no one is going to hire a consulting engineer with no experience or knowledge of the role.